# Which DC comics does this page (featuring the Batcave) come from?

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, batman

Which comic do these panels come from? It was originally posted [here](https://casscain.fandom.com/wiki/File:GothamManorCave1.png).

[image]

Comment: Eventually, together, we'll get every comics appearance of the Batcave identified.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - That would be awesome!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Until someone comes along and draws a new version of the Batcave.  But not all representations of the Batcave will have their provenance questioned, and/or questioned on here.  Thus characterizing the task of identification as a moving target, and hence impossible to complete :D  And why yes, I am fun at parties!

Comment: With my vague understanding of Wiki-pages, isn't all material including graphics supposed to be sourced for possible verification? or for the nerds who like factoids? or is that solely a Wikipedia thing?

Comment: @GWarner Solely a Wikipedia thing. Fandom (formerly Wikia) is nowhere near that strict about... anything, really.

Comment: @GWarner - The page it's sourced from is especially annoying because not only have they not sourced the page, but they've also intentionally redacted the wording that would allow it to be searched for.

Comment: the image name appears to at least link it to Cassandra Cain, so maybe that will help narrow it down..dv from me because yeah...@PaulD.Waite

Comment: @bpvxxvqd You don't need to (and shouldn't) post a bunch of "thanks" comments, especially when you've already thanked the same user(s) before.

Comment: Why do you keep deleting and undeleting this?

Comment: Rather than editing this question with new images, you should create a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Detective Comics #818 June 2006 cover date, https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_818

https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_Face_the_Face_(Collected)
Part 3 of the Face the Face storyline by James Robinson. art by Leonard Kirk, Andy Clarke, and Wayne Faucher.[image]

Comment: hey! you did it! Good work - how'd you come across the answer?