# Which DC comics does this panel come from showing Nightwing on the Batmobile driving towards a ninja?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, episode-identification

Which DC comics does this panel come from?

[image: ninja facing Nightwing who hops on the Batmobile]

Comment: If we're sticking to [one a month](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238155/which-dc-comics-does-this-page-featuring-the-batcave-come-from), we'll never get through all the Batman panels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from *Nightwing* #152 (2009).

[image: full page, showing Nightwing wrecking ninjas]

---

Found with the Google query `dc comics nightwing batmobile ninja batcave site:dc.fandom.com` which returned [the issue's Wikia page](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Nightwing_Vol_2_152).